# Should I mention a mistake made by a third person?

Tags: professorship, communication

A professor asked from me to send one of his books I've had. Because I've had to leave for some days from the country I've arranged with a relative to send the book. However, he ignore it and now the professor sent me an email asking for what happened. In my reply should I mention that the fault is not mine?

Comment: The fault is yours. You failed at the task of ensuring that the professor gets his book. Apologize and make sure it doesn't happen again.

Comment: I agree with @Roland. You should have been checking, reminding the relative, or finding some other means to get the book returned. If it has not yet been returned, find some way to get it returned ASAP.

Comment: 100% agree with @Roland - this is a learning opportunity for real life. If you say something will get done, it is your responsibility to make sure it gets done. Otherwise, people will stop asking you to do things, which in a work environment is a bad thing for you. And, if there is a problem, that problem is detected early, and conveyed early.

Comment: @Roland can you please turn this into an answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I already arranged the shipping, but I feel quite embarrassed. How should I manage the situation in order to justify myself? I don't feel an apology is enough.

Comment: Don't exaggerate it. A firm sorry with **quick and effective remedial action** is a lot better than many guilt-laden apologies.

Comment: I don't think you should try to "justify" yourself. You slipped and didn't follow through adequately. You will just sound like you are trying to shift the blame to someone else when in fact it's your responsibility, no matter who you tried to delegate to.

Comment: @scrappedcola It's the asker's _responsibility_ but it's somebody else's _fault_. Those are two separate concepts.

Comment: Tell the truth and accept responsibility. Why anything else?

Comment: All these comments are so negative towards the asker, like its his responsibility to be at the ready to fulfil his professor's requests at any time. It's not like it's mentioned the book was lent with a deadline.

Comment: @JoãoMiguelBrandão: right, it's not established that the questioner has any responsibility at all to return the book within a week of being asked. Maybe so, maybe not, and the interaction with the professor should be based on the actual situation rather that what the internet assumes based on a three-line question :-) If the professor has unknowingly made a very difficult request, thinking the questioner was in the same building as the book at the time the request was made, then the details are very relevant since the professor might withdraw the request on realising the situation.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It was your task to ensure the book gets returned. You need to take responsibility and apologize. You can mention that you had made arrangements, which failed unfortunately.

It's unlikely that the professor cares about the details. What he cares about is that he didn't get the book (that's why you apologize) and that he can rely on and trust you (that's why you promise it doesn't happen again and make sure it doesn't). This is a learning experience, i.e., you know now that your relative is not reliable and as a consequence your professor trusts you slightly less (but that's not permanent damage). Obviously, make sure he gets the book as soon as possible.

Comment: If you choose to mention the other person to the professor, only refer to them as "someone I know" or another non-description.

Comment: Be sure to take responsibility if you desire to have a good relationship with either the professor or the person.

Comment: @MikeP There's really no need to mention the third person, it sounds too much like "The dog ate it".

Answer (score 22):

I disagree with the accepted answer. Yes, it was your task to return the book so, yes, you need to take responsibility and apologize.

However, you should also mention that you delegated the task to somebody else and they have let you down. Suppose you don't mention this, your relative doesn't send the book for another week and the professor sends you another mail. How are you going to explain that you still haven't done what you said you'd do?

And suppose that you later want to borrow another book. If the professor thinks it's completely your fault that the first book was late, they'll be reluctant to lend you another. But, "I'll never get that person to return another book for me!" is a concrete and believable plan for getting the next book back on time.

Comment: Why does the professor care about the relative?

Comment: *"Why does the professor care about the relative?"*---well, because the relative holds his book!

Comment: @AustinHenley Suppose the asker later wants to borrow another book. "I'll never ask that other person to return the book for me!" is a concrete and believable plan to address the issue of the book being returned late. On the other hand, if the professor believes that it's the asker who's too disorganized to return the book, why would they lend another book. And, as I wrote in my answer, what _is_ the asker going to say if the book hasn't been returned in another week? "Errrrr, it's all my fault but I haven't returned the book because... reasons!"?

Comment: Just passing the blame. Take responsibility and do not mention the relative. This is poor advice. Explain you are away but doing your best our just buy him the book and send it via Amazon.

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS Stop spouting slogans and explain _why_ it's a bad idea to mention the relative. Why do you think the professor will prefer to have the actual situation hidden from them?

Comment: @DavidRicherby because the OP took his book and not some relative he or she has never heard of nor interacted with. Just as the excellent, accepted and highly up-voted answer by Roland states. "It's unlikely that the professor cares about the details. What he cares about is that he didn't get the book". Just as MikeP states in a comment, "There's really no need to mention the third person, it sounds too much like "The dog ate it." Indeed that comment currently has triple the up-votes of your answer. I am not going to dignify the stop spouting slogans part as it is just petty.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you are incorrect in your statement. "Why do you think the professor will prefer to have the actual situation hidden from them" The OP is not hiding the actual situation from the professor if he or she  does what the accepted answer states. No hiding is going on.

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS By not informing the professor that somebody else now has the book, you are hiding the fact that whether they get the book back or not is out of your control. You don't appear to understand that accepting responsibility for something and accepting blame for it are two different things.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: actually I think it's deeper than that. Some people (on the basis of this example: more people than agree with us) genuinely don't see a difference between providing the reason for something and trying to avoid responsibility and/or blame. For that matter we don't know why the questioner was suddenly called out of the country and therefore couldn't just return the book when asked. There really are some people who, on hearing it was due to a death in the family, would scream "don't give me excuses, all I care about is my book and this is your fault!". Such is life.

Comment: Of course, arguably as soon as the professor asked for the book the questioner should have said "I'm not in the country, so I can't send it to you myself, but I'll do my best to have it sent". That ship's sailed, but apparently the professor is now asking "what happened?", not "please make an empty promise while not telling me what happened" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe too many assumptions have to be made in order for the above answers to be completely valid.

Starting from the moment the professor requests this book, he has sent you a task. Since you said you are out of the country, you can either be on vacation or on university work. If it's the first case, your responsibility to even answer in the first place is reduced unlike the second. Anyway, after you accept to do this, the task of getting the book to the professor is now your responsibility.

Since you are not physically able to perform the task, you delegated said task to another agent, which failed to complete it. Did you get initial feedback from the other person that they would follow up on the task? If so, they have drawn the responsiblity to themselves and then failed. If you never had any confirmation this would be performed, then you never passed on the responsibility to complete said task.

Since the professor asked you "what happened", if you think the guilt distribution on the third person is of relevant value, you shouldn't conceal it because the professor would be blaming you whilst you aren't responsible. If he "doesn't care" about the facts that led to the delay, he isn't a very reasonable person in the first place and he should apologise.

Comment: Focusing on correct assignment of blame does not seem productive.

Comment: I agree it's not productive but I was trying to address my opinion on the fact that the accepted answer is only valid in light of an assumed assigment of blame that I'm not so sure of.